# How to set variable to 0 instead of 1 for every nth row

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

New to stackoverflow and SQL, so please be gentle. I'm attempting to create a stored proc that will change variable value from 1 to 0 for every nth row of identity column in table

```
SET @randomBit = IF(SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[js_xxxx] 
WHERE ID%5 AND ID > 0) THEN SET     @randomBit = 0 ELSE 1 END
```

The purpose @randomBit value is to be used to set a bit value, which will then be combined with other fields, then use a while to loop 50 times and then insert into a table.

I

Below would be the ouptut:

```
 Uni
  1
  1
  1
  1
  0
  1
  1
```

Comment: What do you want to do with random bit?   Do you simply want a query from the table with an extra column containing the random bit (0 or 1).  Give an example of what the output should look like to help clarify what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: You do understand that variable only holds **1 value**, so what ever is the last value you set it to that what you will get back.

Comment: Setup as part of a while loop

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, CASE WHEN ID%5=0 THEN 1 else 0 end [RandomBit] FROM [dbo].[js_xxxx]
```

This will give you every 5th ID as 1